# Swift: How to render a text that uses an image as a stroke

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I would like to display a text with a stroke, where the stroke isn't a single color of a certain width, but is consisted of a patterned image.

For example:

[image]

Any suggestions on how that can be accomplished?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63378418/gradient-stroke-on-uilabel-text ?